# Skip further method chaining

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have following observable:

```
_processSelectedPlantWcOb: function (oSelect) {
      let self = this;
      return oSelect
        .map(function (oEvent) {
          // Clean up dates
          let oModel = self.getModel("vmCalSpecialDates");
          oModel.setProperty("/specialDates", []);

          return oEvent.getSource();
        })
        .map(function (oControl) {
          let oItem = oControl.getSelectedItem();
          let aKeys = oItem.getKey().split("/");
          return {plant: aKeys[0], wc: aKeys[1]};
        })
        .flatMap(function (oSelectedItem) {

          let oModel = self.getModel("weightProtocolService");
          let oPlantFilter = new Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.plant);
          let oWcFilter = new Filter("WorkCenter", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.wc);

          return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
            oModel.read("/CostCenterCalendarSet", {
              success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                observer.next(oResponse);
              },
              error: function (oError) {
                observer.error(oError);
              },
              filters: [oPlantFilter, oWcFilter]
            });
          });
        })
        .map(function (oData) {
          return oData.data.results;
        })
        .filter(function (aData) {
          return aData.length > 0;
        })
        .flatMap(function (aData) {
          return Rx.Observable.from(aData)
        })
        .filter(function (oData) {
          let oToday = new Date();
          return oData.InspectionDate.getTime() > oToday.getTime();
        });
    },
```

Suppose I have an instance variable `x = false` that will change in future to `x = true`. On the second map, I want to ask if `x is true`. If yes, it should subscribe it and the stream will stop there.

To clarify what I mean. Consider the second map. This what it will look like:

```
.map(function (oControl) {
    if(x === true) {
        // Subscribe it. stop the stream
    }
    let oItem = oControl.getSelectedItem();
    let aKeys = oItem.getKey().split("/");
    return {plant: aKeys[0], wc: aKeys[1]};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to complete your stream based on `x = true` i would suggest looking at the [`takeUntil`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/takeuntil.md) operator and instead of a variable `x` use a `Subject` on which you will emit something once when `x` becomes `true`.

A Subject is an Observable and an Observer in one so you can use that in the takeUntil to let your stream complete.

Comment: Can you please create an example. I've forget to mention, that is a hot observable. `_createCalendarSelectObservable: function (oCalendar) {
      return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        oCalendar.attachSelect(function (oEvent) {
          observer.onNext(oEvent);
        })
      });
    },` that will trigger every time, when the user press the date.

Comment: With takeUntil, it would not work, because the x variable will be set true if a toggle button will be clicked.